# How do i relate two models using Node js and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i'm making a simple game store like steam, i have a user model and a games model, i need to make a games library and have each user have their own library with games they choose from the store, how do i make it so when a user chooses a game that game is saved into their library using Node js and MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Game and a User model, you can simply create an array of references to the Game model inside the User model. Like this :-

User.js

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // Other user stuff
  games = [{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Game'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Game.js

```
const gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // Other game fields
  users = [{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

Thereafter, you can simple push a game document to a user document using `user.games.push(game)`

Make sure that your 'ref' field has the same name as the model of the object you want to refer to.

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick, but do you know how i can call that push function in html? currently i have a list with some games but i can't think of a way to call that function whenever a user clicks on a game from the list

Comment: @BeyondBirthday08 you can't exactly call database functions inside HTML. You can however chain HTTP methods to the user's input. For example, you can create simple form elements that tell the server which games the user has selected and then push those games to the user's document.

Think of it as simply accepting form inputs. Once you get the input, you can manipulate the database however you wish.

Comment: I see, but first do i need to set the games on the index page to be games that are stored in the database somehow? cause right now they are just list-group-items on a div

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of games in user model and whenever user add a game , the id of that game will be stored in the user model. And then you can retrieve the data by using that id.